# How to use class object variable in another class

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I have two classes in C++

```
     Class A 
     {    
         public: 
             int v; 
     }

     Class B 
     {
         public : 
             void calculation (); 
     }

     void B::calculation () 
     { 
         int i;   
         for (i= 1; i < object_a.v ;i++)    
         {
             //some body    
         } 
      }

      //now I have created an object for class A and for that object I have
      //got some value for "v" 

      int main () 
      { 
          A object_a();
          cout << "The value of variable v in class A is" << object_a.v << ; 
      }
```

For the above sample code I am trying to use a variable retrieved using object_a in another function which is defined in class B. But it throws up an error undeclared. Can someone please help me here how to go about it?

***PS : I am getting the error when it compiles the function "calculation()" in class B***

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable.  Right now it is difficult to parse.

Comment: Hey NathanOliver : Can you please check now

Comment: post the error you get (hint: it might tell you what's wrong...)

Answer (score 5):

As usual. `A object_a();` is not defining a variable object_a of type A. It declares  a function, which is called `object_a`, returns a value of type `A` and accepts no arguments.

Comment: In addition, even if `object_a` was defined as object, he tries to access `object_a`, from within `B::calculation ()`, while it is defined in `main` (scoping issues), and not to mention missing `;` after class declarations.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, the code was so badly formatted, it was hard to notice that. But I think, that error would be most puzzling to OP, so I focused on it.

Answer (score 1):

If method `B::calculation` needs to use an object of class A then you can pass it as an argument to the method. In this case you should define the method with a parameter

For example

```
void calculation ( const A &object_a  ) ;

//...

void B::calculation ( const A &object_a  ) 
{ 
     int i;   
     for (i= 1; i < object_a.v ;i++)    
     {
             //some body    
     } 
}
```

Take into account that this statement

```
A object_a();
```

is a function declaration that has return type A and does not have parameters. You should write instead

```
A object_a;
```

Also you code contains other errors as for example absence of a semicolon after class definitions.